# How to count selected rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how many rows are selected from query along with selected data.

```
SELECT `student`.`student id` AS ID,
    `student unit enrolment`.`session`,
    `student unit enrolment`.`unit code`,
    `units`.`unit name`,
    `workshops`.`campus`,
    `workshops`.`location`,
    CONCAT (
        `teachers`.`first name`,
        " ",
        `teachers`.`last name`
        ) AS Tutor
FROM `student`,
    `student unit enrolment`,
    `units`,
    `workshops`,
    `teachers`
WHERE `student`.`student id` = `student unit enrolment`.`student id`
    AND `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` = `units`.`unit id`
    AND `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` = `workshops`.`unit code`
    AND `workshops`.`teacher id` = `teachers`.`staff id`;
```

Comment: How then is your query result supposed to look like. You know you get a result table that consists of rows and columns. Where to put the total count?

Comment: Share an example of your desired results. Getting a count from a result isn't hard, but displaying along with the data itself doesn't make much sense. It sounds like two seperate queries, or a new column that just repeats the entire count over and over again in each result set record.

Comment: i want to display it any where. may be at the end of resulted table as a count column.

Comment: The join syntax you are using was outdated before MySQL even existed. Please use proper ANSI joins (`FROM ... JOIN ... ON ...`). And I suggest you use table and column names that are valid without backtics, e.g. `student_unit_enrolment`.

Comment: Where are you using the results? Most `MySQL` wrappers/connectors/drivers will have a way to return the count.. it's a waste to try to put it in the query itself

Comment: I don't understand your sample output you have put in the comment. Please edit your request instead and Show the desired output there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query(YOUR_QUERY_HERE);
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: get this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$result = mysql_query(select `student`.`student id` as ID , `student unit enrolm' at line 1

Comment: I've no idea on the error. I don't quite understand what your query is looking to do, although maybe someone else does. I have an idea looking at this quickly that this may instead be better as 2 or more queries, likely inner joined (and perhaps nested) on student_id, unit_code/unit_id, and teacher_id/staff_id. If you explain what kind of output you are looking for perhaps it would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `student`.`student id` as 'Student ID' , `student unit enrolment`.`session` , `student unit enrolment`.`unit code`
 , `units`.`unit name` , `workshops`.`campus` , `workshops`.`location` , CONCAT(`teachers`.`first name`, " " , `teachers`.`last name`) as Tutor , 

(select count(`student`.`student id`) 
from `student` ,  `student unit enrolment` , `units` , `workshops` , `teachers` 
where `student`.`student id` = `student unit enrolment`.`student id` and `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` =  `units`.`unit id`
and `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` =  `workshops`.`unit code`
and `workshops`.`teacher id` = `teachers`.`staff id`
and `student unit enrolment`.`Year` = '2014') as 'Total count of students'

from `student` ,  `student unit enrolment` , `units` , `workshops` , `teachers`
where `student`.`student id` = `student unit enrolment`.`student id`
and `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` =  `units`.`unit id`
and `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` =  `workshops`.`unit code`
and `workshops`.`teacher id` = `teachers`.`staff id`
and  `student unit enrolment`.`Year` = '2014'

Order by `student unit enrolment`.`session` , `student unit enrolment`.`unit code` , `workshops`.`location` , `workshops`.`class times`
```